# Different outputs in console.log(...) and in REPL mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop, console.log

While going around reading a bit about JavaScript coercion, I came a across this.

```
[] + {}; // [object Object]
{} + []; // 0
```

I understand how this works but what I am not able to understand is why does "console.log"ging the above two statements and executing them in REPL results in two different things.

When ran in REPL mode

[image]

```
When ran in browser(Chrome, Firefox) 
console.log([] + {}); // '[object Object]'
console.log({} + []); // '[object Object]'
```

My initial thought was maybe `toString` being called on the console.log parameters, but that is definitely not the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The statement `{} + []` is ambiguous to the JavaScript engine; while *humans* would read this as "the addition of an empty object and an empty array", the JavaScript engine parses this as:

```
// {} + []
{};   // empty block statement with implicit semicolon
+ []; // empty array, coerced into the number 0
// = 0
```

When wrapped in parentheses, such as inside a function, this interpretation is invalid, so the engine falls back to interpreting it as the addition of an object (coerced into a string `'[Object]'`) and an empty array (coerced into a string `''`)